# HPQC - RecordSet Not Displaying All Data

Tags: recordset, hp-quality-center, hp-alm, microfocus

I am using HP (Microfocus) Quality Center 12.5 and designed a button using the toolbar in Workflow.

The following code pulls the first value from the RecordSet but not all values. How do I pull all values from the RecordSet and display it?

```vb
Sub searchDefects()

  On Error Resume Next

    Dim a
     a = InputBox("Enter search query")

set TD1 = TDConnection
set com1 = TD1.command

com1.CommandText = "Select BG_BUG_ID FROM BUG WHERE BG_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%" 
&a &"%'"

set rec1 = com1.Execute

Dim i
DIM msg
msg = ""

rec1.First

 For i = 0 to rec1.RecordCount

     msg = msg & "," & rec1.FieldValue(i) & ","
     rec1.Next()

 Next

MsgBox msg

  On Error GoTo 0


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after trial and error but still don't know the reason behind the root cause and how it is solving it. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
Sub SearchDefectsDescription()
On Error Resume Next

Dim a
a = InputBox("Enter search query for Description field")

set TD1 = TDConnection
set com1 = TD1.command

com1.CommandText = "Select BG_BUG_ID FROM BUG WHERE BG_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%" &a &"%'"
set rec1 = com1.Execute

Dim i
DIM msg
msg = "Bug ID" & vbnewline
rec1.First

If a = vbCancel Then
MsgBox "Search is cancelled"
Exit Sub

ElseIf Len(a) = 0 Then
MsgBox "Search input is empty, plesea try again."
Exit Sub

Else
For i = 0 to rec1.RecordCount

msg = msg & rec1.FieldValue(0) & rec1.FieldValue(1) & " "
rec1.Next()
Next
End If

MsgBox msg

On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```